# Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, unity-game-engine

I have a simple webforms website project. The project uses Microsoft Application Block **Unity 3.5** (DI Container) added via NuGet.

Now I am using this  3rd party web service. After I add Service Reference and build I get this:

> Error 19  Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)   App_WebReferences/MyExternalService/

So I installed Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation but it still keeps complaining about that assembly.

[image]

I tried adding this to my web.config but still doesn't work.

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

***As soon as I uninstall Unity package, all is good. No errors and I can use the Service proxy***

Tried Clean Build, etc. but nothing works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was installing wrong package for getting reference to Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation

**Wrong package**: 
[image]

**Correct package is:**
[image]

Comment: shouldn't the package manager handle this Dependency? I got the same problem

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez I think the web service proxy class need that reference. Unity by itself doesn't require that package.

Comment: @gbs: probably comes late, but I want to tell you that after being over 2 days dealing with this, you saved me. Thank you!